# Can I make Toggle fadeIn Slow and fadeOut Fast?

Tags: jquery

I want toggle to work in such a way that when it fadein, it appears with slow speed and while fading out the speed is fast...

`$('#target').fadeToggle("fast");`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#click-me').click(function(){
    if($('#target').is(':visible')){
       $('#target').fadeOut('fast');
    }
    else{
       $('#target').fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

That should do the work. I've used `if($('#target').is(':visible'))` to check if it is visible or hidden(toggled). Obviously it will fire when you click something with `id="click-me"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle the fading of another element then you can use this function:

HTML:

```
<button id="but" target="#content">Toggle content</button>
```

JS:

```
function fadeToggle() {
    var target = $(this).attr('target');

    if(!$(target).hasClass('hide')) {
        $(target).fadeOut(100).addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $(target).fadeIn(2000).removeClass('hide');            
    }
}

$('#but').click(fadeToggle);
```

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gqhgf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the `#target` to fade in and out immediately at different speeds then you can use something like this (as suggested by others):

```
$("#target").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This will call the `fadeOut()` method on the `#target`, and then the `fadeIn()` method once the first has finished, so your div will disappear and then reappear.

If instead you want to tie the toggle to another related item you could do this:

```
$("#clickme").toggle(function() {
    $("#target").fadeOut('fast');
}, function () {
    $("#target").fadeIn('slow');
});​
```

Where `#clickme` is an another element on the page. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raHwU/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

HTML

```
<button id="but" target="#content">Toggle content</button>
```

JS Code

```
function fadeToggle() {
    var target = $(this).attr('target');

    $(target).fadeOut(1000,function(){
      $(target).fadeIn(2000);  
    });
}

$('#but').click(fadeToggle);
```